# How to get SparkConf from existing SparkSession and create a new SparkSession from gotten SparkConf

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using `spark-sql-2.4.1v`, `spark-cassandra-connector-2.4.1v` with Java. In order to write dataframe into Cassandra db, I am creating a spark

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
                          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",cassandraConfig.getHosts())
                          .set( ...).
```

using which I am creating SparkSession as below

```
 spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName(appName)
        .config("spark.master",deploymentMaster)
        .config(conf)
        .getOrCreate();
```

Using the same I am reading the data from Cassandra table.

Instead of fixed `SparkConf`, I would like to set few more Cassandra properties dynamically and then create SparkSession using which I want to read data from Cassandra table.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can add config with `spark-submit` as  `--conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways by which you can set conf in existing sqlContext or sparkContext.

To add config to existing sparkContext:

```
ss.sparkContext.getConf.set("key","value")
```

To add config to existing sqlContext:

```
ss.sqlContext.setConf("key","value")
```

To get existing sparkConf:

```
ss.sparkContext.getConf()
```

Also config can be set in spark-submit using

```
spark-submit --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=
```

Comment: Hmm, could you clarify what is `ss`? Thanks

Comment: `ss` means spark session.